# Will creating a restore point save my Ruby installation

Tags: windows-8, ruby, system-restore

I am running Ruby and Rails on a Win 8.1 PC, and want to know whether creating a Restore Point via System Properties will allow me to go back to my original Ruby version if I was to install a newer one.

I am dealing with an issue with one of the libraries (Gems), which, according to the [resources I found](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/locomotivecms/NY9BRthywcM), can be fixed by installing Ruby and its DevKit via [Bitnami Ruby Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby).

Comment: Restore points are volatile and can disappear at any moment for many reasons - often unknown. I would suggest to make images. See here ==> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I

Comment: @whs Thanks! Ended up doing both, creating a restore point and creating an image.

Comment: You are welcome. Refresh the images frequently so that you are always up-to-date.